# Creating and accessing __doc__

Tags: python, doc

Im going through the book Dive into Python 3 and in one of its parts theres a .py file which contains a function that has a **triple quoted** string that as the book explains it, is a document.
When I go into the python shell and import said file and write 
`print(humansize.approximate_size.__doc__)`
it gives me back the said triple quoted string.
I decided Id give it a try myself and created a triple quoted string right under the other one. Saved the file and ran the same code in the python shell - but only the first one appeared. Why is that?
Do i need to install some separate tool to document code ?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't add a second string, just add more to, or edit, the same string. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It's helpful to include in your question code that other people could run and re-create the issue you are seeing. A 'minimal working example'

Comment: There is quite a bit of useful information for you here - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Comment: Take note that there is nothing special about using triple quote for docstrings, other than that they allow for multiline literals. Using single quotes would be just as valid for single line docstrings.